# Using property placeholder to decide routes and camel contexts

Tags: jvm, apache-camel, jvm-arguments

Is there any way where I can group Camel Contexts or routes based on property value?

I have my environments defined as -Denv="preprod" and I want to group/decide routes and contexts based on that. For example:

For dev env:

```
<camel:route id="foo" >
        <camel:from uri="seda:start"/>
        <camel:to uri="mock:result"/>
    </camel:route>
```

For Production:

```
<camel:route id="foo" >
            <camel:from uri="seda:start"/>
            <camel:to uri="jmsqueue:result"/>
        </camel:route>
```

I am using Spring Application Context to declare Camel Contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you use Spring then you can use spring property placeholders, and have different .properties file per environment. And then define the endpoints as `<endpoint>` and refer to these endpoints in the route. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Then its a matter of configuring spring property placeholder to use your -D system environment to load the .properties file for the given environment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Spring placeholder's to manage your routes, consider managing your configuration with Camel's Properties Component [1]. I personally prefer to be dependent on Camel's API instead of Spring's when configuring my routes.

[1] http://camel.apache.org/properties.html